# Is there a term for a "union" or "meeting" between Kings?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a "union" or "meeting" between Kings?

An example would be: four different kings go to a meeting in one's realm to discuss politics. (Though I really don't know if it was a common practice or has a name.)

Comment: What time period are you talking about?

Comment: Such meetings weren't commonplace and they often got their own names. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_the_Cloth_of_Gold

Answer (score 3):

The modern term for this is "summit". From [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193987?rskey=RlQwAk&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> A meeting or series of meetings between the heads of state or government of two or more countries, convened for the purpose of discussing matters of international importance.

However, the earliest use this attests is in 1955. So it was not in use in medieval times when meetings among royalty might have been common.

Answer (score 1):

I like “summit” but if that is too modern for your purposes, consider “conclave” instead.

The Wiki page for [the Field of the Cloth of Gold
meeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_the_Cloth_of_Gold) calls the event a “summit” but the linked page for “summit” lists no summits that were called by that name until 1974, and  no summits by any name before WW2.  I guess in 1520, it was rare to have an important enough issue to  make very senior officials endure that risk and expense and delay to meet face-to-face, and they would usually send representatives instead.

[Cambridge](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/conclave):

> 1] a private or secret meeting.
>
> 2] an assembly or gathering, especially one that has special authority, power, or influence:
> *a conclave of political leaders.*

Comment: This account of the [Congress of Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congress_of_Vienna#The_Congress_format) gives some explanation of the background.

Comment: *Conclave* is derived from "with key," meaning a meeting behind locked doors, and specifically the meeting which elects a pope. To give it a general meaning is a bit of a stretch, it seems to me. (Cambridge may merely be documenting that it has been so used, not that it's a good idea or even reasonable to do so.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach — “conclave” used to mean “closed meeting of senior officials” is reasonably well-established, and strikes me as a good usage to establish if it did not already exist.  To use it for a fully open-to-the-press summit would be at odds with its etymology, of course.